# AWS Simple Email Sdk in asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

I already tried AWS .net sdk and create com component, but that's not working because it depends on aws.core.dll.

Do Amazon or third party has Simple Email SDK for asp classic VB Script?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example [taken from here](https://www.saotn.org/authenticated-smtp-tls/):

```
' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526318(v=exchg.10).aspx
' Its good practice to use the module constants defined in the
' type library for the names.  The full names are used here to
' indicate that this is what is going on

 Const cdoSendUsingMethod        = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing"
 Const cdoSendUsingPort          = 2
 Const cdoSMTPServer             = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver"
 Const cdoSMTPServerPort         = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport"
 Const cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout  = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout"
 Const cdoSMTPAuthenticate       = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"
 Const cdoBasic                  = 1
 Const cdoSendUserName           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername"
 Const cdoSendPassword           = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword"
 'Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
 Const cdoSendTLS        = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl"

' create CDOSYS objects
Set myMail.Configuration = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
Set Fields = myMail.Configuration.Fields

' CDOSYS SMTP configuration
With Fields
 .Item(cdoSendUsingMethod)   = cdoSendUsingPort
 .Item(cdoSMTPServer)        = "smtp.example.com"
 .Item(cdoSMTPServerPort)    = 25 ' SMTP port, 587 is possible too
 .Item(cdoSMTPAuthenticate)  = cdoBasic ' send using SMTP authentication
 .Item(cdoSendUserName)      = "emailadress@example.com"  ' email address username
 .Item(cdoSendPassword)      = "password"
 .Item(cdoSendTLS)           = true 'send using TLS
 .Update 'update the configuration
End With
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this isn't a third party component from AWS or anyone else, it uses CDO which is included with Windows server editions.  This is probably the best CDO tutorial I've found to date. http://www.powerasp.net/content/new/sending_email_cdosys.asp